# Java: How to make thread loop until condition met

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop, parallel-processing, dsa

I want to implement the DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm) algorithm using Java. When building the p and q keys, I want the result of (p-1) mod q = 0. This is the code that I made, when I call the contents of q2 (result of p-1 mod q) it doesn't return 0.

```
package random;
import java.util.Random;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class RandomPrime implements Runnable {
    BigInteger randomNumber = BigInteger.probablePrime(512, new Random());
    BigInteger randomNumber2 = BigInteger.probablePrime(160, new Random());
    BigInteger p = randomNumber;
    BigInteger q = randomNumber2;
    BigInteger q2 = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).remainder(q);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!q2.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)){
            randomNumber = BigInteger.probablePrime(512, new Random());
            randomNumber2 = BigInteger.probablePrime(160, new Random());
            p = randomNumber;
            q = randomNumber2;
            q2 = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).remainder(q);
        }
    }

    public BigInteger getPValue() {
        return p;
    }
    public BigInteger getQValue() {
        return q;
    }
    public BigInteger getQ2Value() {
        return q2;
    }
}
```

This is how I call it

```
RandomPrime rPrime = new RandomPrime();
Thread thread = new Thread(rPrime);
thread.start();
BigInteger p = rPrime.getPValue();
BigInteger q = rPrime.getQValue();
BigInteger q2 = rPrime.getQ2Value();

System.out.println("p:" +p);
System.out.println("q:" +q);
System.out.println("q2:" +q2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You start the thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(rPrime);
thread.start();
```

and you immediately call for the result:

```
BigInteger p = rPrime.getPValue();
BigInteger q = rPrime.getQValue();
BigInteger q2 = rPrime.getQ2Value();

System.out.println("p:" +p);
System.out.println("q:" +q);
System.out.println("q2:" +q2);
```

You did not give enough time for the thread to actually finish to performed its assigned work. In your case calling [thread.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

> **The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of
> another.**

after the start would be enough, *i.e.,* making the initial thread to wait for the  second thread to finish, namely:

```
RandomPrime rPrime = new RandomPrime();
Thread thread = new Thread(rPrime);
thread.start();

try {
     thread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // do something
}
BigInteger p = rPrime.getPValue();
BigInteger q = rPrime.getQValue();
BigInteger q2 = rPrime.getQ2Value();

System.out.println("p:" +p);
System.out.println("q:" +q);
System.out.println("q2:" +q2);
```

Comment: Okay, it looks like it's working properly. However, when I run it it feels really, really long to match the p and q values. Does Java have a solution for that?

Comment: @RheaDavinAdhiskara no, that is because you are generating both number randomly, naturally it can take an undefined amount of time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the algorithm you're implementing. But there is at least the following problem:

You are not waiting for the thread to finish. One solution for this could be to add a `thread.join()` immediately after your call to `thread.start()`. However, this makes the separate thread kind of useless since your main thread does not do any work while the new thread is running.